# Compiling root style file as Less with Angular CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm trying to use Less on the root stylesheet generated by Angular CLI. After some searching, I noticed I can create a project with Less configured with `ng new project_name --style less`, but still, the app doesn't seem to want to load the styles in my style.less. If I change it to style.css, it works fine. For the note, less files in components work just fine.

I'm not sure if I'm not understanding this or how to debug it.

Comment: I appreciate this is an old question, but it probably needed a bit more information to tempt people into answering. Readers in general are looking for an [mcve].

Comment: Thanks (and thanks for fixing all my old questions), but in this sort of case, what example could I give? It's a CLI command that isn't working correctly, I provided the CLI command I tried.

Comment: It's a fair point, and I'm not exactly sure - I pondered that earlier. I suggest it because there is a desire on Stack Overflow for detail even if it would be hard to provide - it is unfortunately a result of our getting a lot of questions where the problem is not reproducible with the detail given, so edge cases tend to suffer the same.

Comment: This sounds unreproducible too, but not for the want of extra detail. Am I right in thinking this did not happen with a new project, just this specific one? If so, and if readers cannot repro it themselves, it unfortunately may not be an answerable question.

Comment: Yah, when I asked, I thought it may not be answerable. At the time, I know there were issues with the way angular-cli was creating projects for LESS/SASS, so I thought I'd ask in case there was a bug report or fix that I missed, or in case I just missed something entirely obvious. I always figure a bunch of "edge case" scenarios are actually people like me doing (or not doing) something obvious.